# Conflict between qDebug and SDL

Tags: qt, sdl, qtcore

I work on Mac OS 10.8.5 and Qt 5.1.1 with among other things, `qdebug` class which work well with some projects and doesn't compile with some others. I've already tried to re-install Qt which didn't change a thing.

It is certainly due to the use of SDL library (?!) but it used to work fine. Here's a part of the compilation output :

```
In file included from ../../Stage/Joker/tests/SDLTest/main.cpp:7:
In file included from /Applications/QT/5.1.1/clang_64/include/QtCore/QDebug:1:
In file included from /Applications/QT/5.1.1/clang_64/include/QtCore/qdebug.h:46:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qhash.h:46:
/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qchar.h:76:5: error: unknown type name 'QT_ASCII_CAST_WARN_CONSTRUCTOR'
    QT_ASCII_CAST_WARN_CONSTRUCTOR QChar(char c);
    ^
```

If needed, I can provide more output or unworking Qt classes.

I build my code with Qt => Build => Run
Unfortunatly, I'm unable to reproduce the code on an other computer.

Here's the pro file (which work well with all my co-workers, except me) :

```
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
OBJECTIVE_HEADERS += ../../libs/PhGraphic/SDLMain.h
OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += ../../libs/PhGraphic/SDLMain.m
LIBS += -framework Cocoa
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
LIBS += -F/Library/Frameworks

LIBS += -framework SDL -framework SDL_image -framework SDL_ttf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd once had this problem after installing a software: it created a *QtCore.framework* in the */Library/Framework* folder that overrided the QtCore of your current Qt kit (due to QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks).

Comment: You're right! Furthermore this famous line helped my co-workers with SDL while I was in holidays, my boss alarmed me about this but I didn't make the link. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Very interesting. That really means that qmake needs to support specifying library inclusion order. One needs to be able to specify that Qt comes before some other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's `qDebug`, and there are two overloads:

   - a stream-returning function

     ```
     qDebug() << "foo";
     ```
   - a printf-style function

     ```
     qDebug("foo");
     ```
2. You need to provide a minimum reproducible test case for us to help you.
3. How are you building your code? Are you using qmake to produce the Makefile? We'd need to see the .pro file at the minimum, and *please* minimize it by removing useless boilerplate comments etc.

Comment: I've edited my post with a simpler snippet which doesn't work either